# Inject a Map attribute in a Spring service

Tags: spring

[B]I have a class called RechercheInfosTableImpl, and annotated @Component
This class has one attribute of type  Map
I want only by annotation, instantiate this attribute and inject it during the instanciation with Spring of the class RechercheInfosTableImpl.[/B]

This is my class and it does not work (i tried many options and they don't work and i loose my lucidity) :

```
package fr.msa.agora.bp0gos.local.lanceur;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import fr.cnamts.rfos.nomenclature.CodeValeur;
import fr.cnamts.rfos.nomenclature.Table;
import fr.cnamts.rfos.nomenclature.Valeurs;

/**
 * Service de recherche d'informations sur les tables.
 * 
 * 
 */
@Component
public class RechercheInfosTableImpl implements RechercheInfosTable {

    [B]/**
     * Map [clé = "Nom d'une Table" , valeur = "Code Qualifiant associé à cette table"].
     */
    @Resource
    private final Map<String, String> tableauAssociatifNomTableETCodeQualifiantTable;

    /**
     * @param pTableauAssociatifNomTableETCodeQualifiantTable
     */
    @Autowired
    public RechercheInfosTableImpl(final Map<String, String> pMap) {
        tableauAssociatifNomTableETCodeQualifiantTable = pMap;
    }[/B]   

 /**
     * Alimente la Map [clé = "Nom d'une table" , valeur = "Code Qualifiant de cette table"]
     * 
     * @param pNomTable table CNAM lue.
     */
    @Override
    public void extraireInfosTable(final Table pTable) {
        synchronized (tableauAssociatifNomTableETCodeQualifiantTable) {
            // si la table lue n'est pas stockée dans le tableau associatif
            if (!tableauAssociatifNomTableETCodeQualifiantTable.containsKey(pTable.getNom())) {
                boolean valeurTrouvee = false;
                final Iterator<Valeurs> iterateurValeurs = pTable.getValeurs().iterator();
                Valeurs valeurLue;

                // une valeur = une liste de codes

                // parcourir les valeurs de cette map
                // jusqu'à ce qu'on arrive au bout de toutes ces valeurs (ces listes de codes)
                // ou bien qu'on tombe, pour une de ces valeurs, sur un code principal
                while (iterateurValeurs.hasNext() && !valeurTrouvee) {
                    valeurLue = iterateurValeurs.next();
                    // si la liste de codes de la valeur lu n'est pas vide
                    if ((valeurLue != null) && (valeurLue.getCode() != null) && (!valeurLue.getCode().isEmpty())) {
                        final Iterator<CodeValeur> iterateurCodesValeur = valeurLue.getCode().iterator();
                        while (iterateurCodesValeur.hasNext() && !valeurTrouvee) {
                            final CodeValeur codeValeurlue = iterateurCodesValeur.next();
                            // si on trouve pour la valeur lue, un code principal
                            if ((codeValeurlue != null) && ("P".equalsIgnoreCase(codeValeurlue.getR()))
                                    && (!codeValeurlue.getQ().isEmpty())) {
                                // associer, dans le tableur associatif attribut
                                // le nom de la table
                                // et le code qualifiant de cette table
                                tableauAssociatifNomTableETCodeQualifiantTable.put(pTable.getNom(),
                                        codeValeurlue.getQ());
                                valeurTrouvee = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see fr.msa.agora.bp0gos.local.lanceur.RechercheInfosTable#afficherInformations()
     */
    @Override
    public List<String> afficherInformations() {
        final List<String> listeAAfficher = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (final Entry<String, String> element : tableauAssociatifNomTableETCodeQualifiantTable.entrySet()) {
            listeAAfficher.add("Table => Nom : " + element.getKey() + " Code Qualifiant : " + element.getValue());
        }
        return listeAAfficher;
    }
}
```

And there are the errors obtained during the execution of the program :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'lanceurApplicationExtractionDonneesTable' defined in file [D:\platformsg2_R_64\workspace\gos-injecteur-flux-rfos\target\classes\fr\msa\agora\bp0gos\local\lanceur\LanceurApplicationExtractionDonneesTable.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 2 of type [fr.msa.agora.bp0gos.local.lanceur.RechercheInfosTable]: : Error creating bean with name 'rechercheInfosTableImpl' defined in file [D:\platformsg2_R_64\workspace\gos-injecteur-flux-rfos\target\classes\fr\msa\agora\bp0gos\local\lanceur\RechercheInfosTableImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [java.util.Map]: : No matching bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency [map with value type java.lang.String]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency [map with value type java.lang.String]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'rechercheInfosTableImpl' defined in file [D:\platformsg2_R_64\workspace\gos-injecteur-flux-rfos\target\classes\fr\msa\agora\bp0gos\local\lanceur\RechercheInfosTableImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [java.util.Map]: : No matching bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency [map with value type java.lang.String]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency [map with value type java.lang.String]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:718)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:993)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:897)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:574)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at fr.msa.agora.bp0gos.local.lanceur.GestionApplicationStatic.chargementSpring(GestionApplicationStatic.java:36)
    at fr.msa.agora.bp0gos.local.lanceur.LanceurApplicationExtractionDonneesTable.chargerSpring(LanceurApplicationExtractionDonneesTable.java:128)
    at fr.msa.agora.bp0gos.local.lanceur.LanceurApplicationExtractionDonneesTable.main(LanceurApplicationExtractionDonneesTable.java:60)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'rechercheInfosTableImpl' defined in file [D:\platformsg2_R_64\workspace\gos-injecteur-flux-rfos\target\classes\fr\msa\agora\bp0gos\local\lanceur\RechercheInfosTableImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [java.util.Map]: : No matching bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency [map with value type java.lang.String]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency [map with value type java.lang.String]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:718)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:993)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:897)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:838)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:780)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:697)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:784)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:711)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency [map with value type java.lang.String]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:914)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:697)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:784)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:711)
    ... 29 more
```

Using onlys annotations (without modifying XML files), how inject my Map attribute in my service ?
In fact, one ask me to use only annotations.

If i remove the constructor with the @Autowired annotation, even the compilation does not work.

Thanks in advance ,
  Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you're trying to do from your code. But injecting a `Map` in spring would require a `Map<String, Class<?>>` signature. Class must be an `interface`. Spring will then automatically wire each impl class with its assigned bean name into that map.

At the moment you're trying to inject a `String`, which is impossible as a string is not a spring managed object.

Or, if I misunderstood you and you want really to inject a `Map<String, String>`: create a wrapper class that holds the map you wish to inject, eg:

```
@Component
class MapWrapper {
    private Map<String, String> map;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much membersound. it works. Like you said, i created a wrapper with a Map attribute (Map<String, String>) and i used this wrapper to access this map, and to store date in this Map.

Comment: I wanted to mark your answer as useful, but i can't because my reputation is under 15.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `@Qualifier("[name of map]")` additionally to the `@Resource` Annotation.

And Spring sometimes has problems with the concrete types. In my case I needed to create a `HashMap` typed setter, that the injection works fine.

Comment: Thanks Markus. I will try it. I let you know.

Comment: I try in this way : I put the type of my attribute HashMap, and i associate to it an @Qualifier annotation, and a setter without annotation. But it does not work. Have i forgotten something ? Please let me know Markus. Thank you,

Comment: Would you post your bean definition? Did Ou try to use autobiography?

Comment: Thanks Markus. In fact,  i created a wrapper with a Map attribute (Map<String, String>) and i used this wrapper to access this map, and to store date in this Map.

Comment: Markus, I wanted to mark your answer as useful, but i can't because my reputation is under 15.